# Can't get expo to run on android emulator (macOS)

Tags: android, macos, react-native, adb, expo

I'm getting into react native and I'm trying hard to get expo running on an android studio device.

It's a pixel with API28.

My app runs fine on the iOS simulator, but whenever I'm trying to open it on the android emulator, it tells me that there are multiple adb devices running and I can't do anything about it.

I tried several "kill emulator" commands that I found around here, but they don't do anything.

Whenever I run `adb devices` i get two of them. 
one that's running and one that's offline.

I'm sure I'm not the only one that has ever run into this. 
Learning react native on just one platform is lame, haha.

Who can help?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: make sure you are running only one adb on your pc

Comment: how would i check that on a mac?

Comment: I had in fact running two expos. but i have the same problem